# How to make our database secure

Tags: android, sqlite, security

I am using database in one of my application while creating database. I am setting the MODE as private.
I want to know will it be enough to make it secure or do I have to go through encryption-decryption process to make it secure.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, SharedPreferences and SQLite databases are only as secure as the user let them be, but in most cases they'll do just fine (make sure you encrypt any passwords though).

The thing is that they're two ways of accessing a specific applications' databases:

1. If the device is rooted, pretty much anyone can gain access to them
2. If a malicious app uses the `Context` from `myapplication`, it could be able to access them

To sum it up: They're secure most of the time, but protect sensitive data just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..can you tell me one more thing? My Question is: If I have installed my application on to my device we know internally "data" folder is there inside which the db creates..my db is also present there...is there any way by which I can b able to pull out my db file once installed to my android device??

Comment: that means my db will get expose to client and he can leak/access my data.Do u know any tool by which I can able to pull out Database from device?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing `your`corporate secrets on the user's device. ;-) On a more serious note, this seems like something you might want to check out: http://sourceforge.net/projects/asqlitemanager/

Comment: Android has protections in place to guard the data folder.  If a user breaks those permissions and allows a malicious app to get at the data, then 99% of the time it is their fault. The other 1% is an exploit that gets root without asking the users permission.  If you really need to be protecting against that you might want to get someone more experienced to create this application.